# Extract parts of an .deb archive with PHP

Tags: php, pear

I want to extract the `control.tar.gz` of an `.deb` file into a directory with PHP. 
Should be possible with `File_Archive::extract`.

This is the current code I have:

```
$tmp = 'testdebs';

foreach (glob("../debs/*.deb") as $t1) {

    //$t1 correct
    echo "current deb: " . $t1 . "\n";

    $fname = ($t1);

    $md5 = md5_file($t1);

    $sha1 = sha1_file($t1);
    $sha256 = hash_file('sha256', $t1);
    $sha512 = hash_file('sha512', $t1);

    $size = filesize($t1);

    echo "size: " . $size . "\n";


    //Also tried: 
    // File_Archive::extract(File_Archive::read($t1 . '/control.tar.gz/'), File_Archive::toFiles("/var/www/some_directory/manage/testdebs/"));
    // and:
    // File_Archive::extract(File_Archive::read($t1 . '/control.tar.gz/'), File_Archive::toFiles($tmp));

    File_Archive::extract(File_Archive::read($t1 . '/control.tar.gz/'), File_Archive::toFiles("/var/www/some_directory/manage/testdebs"));


    $aLinesFile = file("testdebs/control", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    echo "aLinesFile: " . $aLinesFile . "\n";

    $pack = end(preg_grep('/^Package\:.*$/i', $aLinesFile));

    echo $pack . "\n";

}
```

Running this code does literaly nothing. `$t1` has always the correct value for a `.deb` (which means that the `.deb` is found in the directory). I also get the correct `filesize` for the `.deb` File.

My `testdeb` directy stays empty, so there must be an error with the `File_Archive::extract` I guess. In the error log I only find the following warning:

> PHP Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /var/www/some_directory/manage/generate.php on line 78

line 78 is `$pack = end(preg_grep('/^Package\:.*$/i', $aLinesFile));` in the code sample. 
The *testdeb* directory is set to *775* and is owned by the user (*www-data*) so I assume the rights are correct.

Is there any way to find out more about the error or to enable some deeper logging to fix this error?

Comment: Yes, output results of `preg_grep('/^Package\:.*$/i', $aLinesFile)` and understand why are they `null`.

Comment: @u_mulder yeah it is null because there seems to be an error with the `File_Archive::extract` command because my `testdeb` directory stays empty and nothing gets extracted into this directory.

Comment: Not really sure, but `$t1` is a file. What do you expect from `$t1 . '/control.tar.gz/'`?

Comment: And why would it contain a `control.tar.gz` rather than `.xz`?

Comment: Cydia .deb files contain a control.tar.gz. If I extract the file on my computer I also see the control.tar.gz which then contains the normal control file where the Package is set (and some other infos).

Comment: @u_mulder `$t1 . '/control.tar.gz/'` is the file inside the .deb file. Also shown here: https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.file-archive.examples.php under * Extracting a file from an archive*.